# MySQL ")" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

I need to import my mod-ap.sql file using the Reverse Engineering MySQL Create Script import command. 
When I go to do so I receive an error at two locations (10, 0) and (43, 0).
Error:
")" is invalid at this position, expecting an identifier.

Lines 7-15;

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ap;
CREATE DATABASE ap;
USE ap;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vendors (
vendorID       INT          NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, -- PG 551 : 1-2 per professor
vendorName     VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
vendorAddress  VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
vendorCity     VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL,
```

Lines 41 - 46

```
);

-- #2 create table called audit : 2.1-2.7 add columns
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS audit (
auditID                 INT           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
auditorFirstName        VARCHAR(45)   NOT NULL,
```

*** Line 10 is empty

*** Line 43 is blocked out using a -- to comment

I've tried researching this issue and came up with a few bugs in workbench or specific words being reserved but nothing closely relating to this.

Comment: Make sure you don't have an extra `,` before the `)` that ends the list of columns.

Comment: I suspect the line numbers in the error messages don't correspond to lines in the whole script.

Comment: @Barmar The numbers did not correspond to the lines, just the beginning of the code where the problem resided. The problem was the comma at the end where I commented out a piece of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Remove any commas before the closing bracket `)`

Answer (score 2):

Could be you used in one line a hyphen (') for field name instead of backticks (`) or the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

This error could be because you have not specified the **Table Names** in both condition. Sometimes it is necessary to specify a table name because you need to refer to that table later in database